# My StoryBoard is Messed Up Xcode9

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

My Storyboard is messed all of my views are messed it was working fine and suddenly this happened anyone please tell me how to solve this i do not have any backup i am in big trouble check this screenshot.

[StoryBoard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb3Y0.png)

[Close Picture Of StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6rQx.png)

Comment: Quite hard to see from that image how anything is messed up since it’s zoomed out so much the views are tiny. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Just close Xcode and reopen it and go to story board. Every things will be fine.

Comment: share your storyboard link

Comment: I did but nothing happen. @iPatel

Comment: Flagged for closing. Please, learn what and how a good question is. You've posted **no** details. You've posted **nothing** of substance where anyone can actually help you.

Comment: I have added second screenshot @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: It’s as unclear as the previous one. Zoom to 100% if you want us to actually see the views

Comment: Have you tried changing the selected device (bottom left of the screen)? After installing XCode 9 it defaulted to iPhone 8 and switching to the original device straightened things out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open any swift file, clean project.

Close project and quit xcode (Right click xcode and quit)

Open back project, you should be in the swift file you previously opened.

Go to the storyboard file again.

One clue I know of which caused this issue is that, if you have a compiler error, u click on the error, and it brings you to storyboard file from that error message. I've experienced this since xcode 8.0 till 9.0. Not sure if this happens to me only.

So try to open storyboard file every time using Project Navigator at the left hand side.